# How to get an array of strings without using argv - CS50 pset2

Tags: cs50

I'm currently doing the CS50 Harvard Course and I'm stuck in problem set 2.
I made this program that takes a name and prints the initials, it takes the name in the command line. How can I use **get_string()** instead of argv, and argc which is very unorthodox and sloppy, so I can prompt the user to give me her/his name. Thank you.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

//How do I use Get_string() so I don't have to use argv and argc?? 


//iterate over strings on the vector (words)
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        //prints the 0 character of each string, use "toupper" to convert into capital letters
        printf("%c", toupper(argv[i][0]));
    
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Array,
let's say for 10 names

```
string name[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    name[i] = get_string("Enter your name: /n");
}
```